# Trouble using core data with different simulators

Tags: core-data

I am trying to make a small language learning app using Core Data. Everything is working fine except for one thing: if I use the simulator( iphone SE, for instance) that was selected when I was creating the app, I have got access to all the data from my attributes. But when I switch to another simulator (not an actual device) to run the app , all the attributes look like there are empty, and  I do not get nothing. 
So if I try to save new data using a different simulator at the top left, i can only get acces to those data only if i run the same simulator that was used to save them.

In a nuthshell, i want to get access to my recorded data no matter what simulator I use.
Can anyone help me solve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

Each simulator is independent, and different simulators do not share data. Each one acts like it's a separate simulated device. This isn't about Core Data-- it would be the same for any data your app saves. There's no good way to share data between simulators. Some command-line Unix wizardry *might* get shared files but it's not built in or supported.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Harrington. I am kind of novice to xcode. If I understand what you have said, there is no way to run my core data app on an actual device before putting it on the app store for evaluation.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Harrington. I am kind of novice to xcode. If I understand what you have said, there is no way to run my core data app on an actual device before putting it on the app store for evaluation.  Another question: do i have to keep the same simulator until i upload the app to the appstore? How can i test this kind of app on actual device since I cannot transfert data from simulator to simulator?

Comment: You can and should test on a device before submitting the app to the store. Using a simulator doesn't affect that.

Comment: As for the data, if you generated in the app in one simulator, install the app in another simulator or on a device and generate the same (or similar) data. That's pretty much how it works.